# How size is allocated in c++ for array?

Tags: c++

If we initialize array with 4 elements, for example:

```
int array[4];
```

Can we assign values like this because it is also taking 4 values:

```
for(int i=5;i<9;i++){    
    cin>>array[i];
}
```

Comment: No you would access the array out of bounds.

Comment: If you use `std::vector` you can `push_back` as many entries as you can fit in memory.

Comment: try to run it in any online compiler it is working.

Comment: "Working" and "may cause unpredictable behaviour and crashes" are often very hard to differentiate. This code is absolutely, positively, *undefined behaviour* and can and will crash when you least expected it.

Comment: @YadvendraKumar It is undefined behavior. It includes "working" but also every other behavior.

Comment: `cin>>array[i -5];`

Comment: Have you tried compiling the code with what you just wrote? This will lead to out of bounds errors because array[5], does not exist. Same with 6, 7, and 8.

Comment: @Sailanarmo  C++ doesn't have "out of bounds errors" for arrays.

Comment: @YadvendraKumar Like most newbies you are having trouble with the concept of undefined behaviour (UB). Your program has UB because of the out of bounds array access. UB means what it says, the behaviour is undefined. C++ doesn't say your program will not 'work', it just says the behaviour is undefined, it could work, it could crash, it could do anything. Obviously it's better to avoid UB.

Comment: @Sailanarmo sadly that is not the case, the compiler will not complain, and neither will the run time. It will just smash the stack.

Comment: Someone has upvoted this question. Strange

Comment: @P__J__ I upvoted the question, what's strange about it?

Comment: Someone qualified should write a reference Q/A about UB, if there isn't one yet...

Comment: @P__J__ It's possible that the OP had never heard the term 'out of bounds' until they read the answers here.

Comment: Why does C++ allow bad code like this? Because defending against it requires testing, most likely at runtime, and those tests will make the produced code slower. People flock to C and C++ for the speed that it offers, but that speed comes at a cost. To quote good ol' Uncle Ben, "With great power comes great responsibility."

Answer (score 5):

Out-of-bounds access on an array has *undefined behaviour*, which is another way of saying "unintended consequences":

```
int a[4];
int b[4];

for(int i=5;i<9;i++){
  a[i] = i;
}
```

In a debugger watch what it's doing and in particular watch what happens to `b`.

This may or may not crash, but it's still broken code. C++ will not always alert you to such situations, it's your responsibility as a developer to be aware of what's allowed and not allowed when accessing certain structures.

Accessing an array out of bounds doesn't always cause a crash, but it is always problematic. Try with `i = 999999` or `i = -9` and see what happens.

The problem with undefined behaviour is that it may appear to be working but these unintended consequences eventually catch up with you. This makes debugging your code very difficult as this out-of-bounds write may stomp a variable that you need somewhere else minutes or hours after the initial mistake, and *then* your program crashes. Those sorts of bugs are the most infuriating to fix since the time between the cause and effect is extremely long.

It's the same as how throwing lit matches in the garbage may not cause a fire every time but when it does cause a fire you may not notice until it's too late. In C++ you *must* be extremely vigilant about not introducing undefined behaviour into your code.

Answer (score 3):

You are mixing up two constructs - the logic used to iterate in a loop and the indexing of an array.

You may use

```
for(int i=5;i<9;i++){
  ...
}
```

to run the loop four times. However, you many not use those values of `i` to access the array. The array index has to be offset appropriately so it is valid.

```
for(int i=5;i<9;i++){
   int index = i - 5;
   std::cin >> array[index];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you get an array with 4 slots. Those slots are

```
array[0]
array[1]
array[2]
array[3]
```

So your code is incorrect. It might seem to work, but its still wrong due to whats called Undefined Behavior, next week it might fail

Note. You are better off using std::vector in c++

Comment: as my comment says, it might seem to work, but this is UB.

Comment: @YadvendraKumar if you do not listen - code this way. Eventually you will end up here (or somewhere else) with the question "why this code is not working"

Answer (score 1):

> can we allocate value like this because it is also taking 4 values:
>
> ```
> for(int i=5;i<9;i++){
>
>  cin>>array[i];
> ```

No, we can't. Since the size of the array is 4, the only indices that can be accessed are 0,1,2 and 3. Accessing any other index will have undefined behaviour.

> try to run it in any online compiler it is working.

The behaviour is undefined. Possible behaviours include, none of which are guaranteed:

```
 - working
 - not working
 - random output
 - non-random output
 - the expected output
 - unexpected output
 - no output
 - any output
 - crashing at random
 - crashing always
 - not crashing
 - corruption of data
 - different behaviour, when executed on another system
 -                    , when compiled with another compiler
 -                    , on tuesday
 -                    , only when you are not looking
 - same behaviour in all of the above cases
 - anything else within the power of the computer (hopefully limited by the OS)
```

Comment: Forgot one:  Destroy the Earth*, and all living things upon it.  * If this was a result of the Microsoft compiler, please file an issue with User Voice and Microsoft will prioritize it accordingly.